# foursquare places API GET request returns 503 Bad Gateway or Header overflow

Tags: javascript, api, get, query-string

### Problem

I am trying to fetch coffee stores around a specific latitude, longitude within a certain radius but I am failing.

---

My query string looks like this

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/search?ll="41.8781,-87.6298"&radius=10000&query="coffee"
```

---

I've provided my authentication key inside of the header

[image: output from postman]

---

Why am I getting this response?
503 means that the server is down, but the foursquare website tells that the website is up and running. What am I doing wrong?
[link to places api](https://developer.foursquare.com/reference/place-search)

Comment: Having the same issue. I can get it to work via the places test dashboard, and also through curl'ing via my CLI,. but the sdk() with the proper headers keeps returnnig 503 Header Overflow errors. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error in code and on Postman. In Postman, I had to uncheck the existing Accept header and add another with the `application/json` value to get it to work correctly.

[Screenshot of Postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvuQM.png)

Comment: Please include all details to your answer in text, not in a screenshot. The screenshot source might end up 404ing and that will affect users of this site in the future.

Comment: They are. I only added the screenshot to be supplemental.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion there.